# In openGL: how to move an object( cube) on a plane surface with keep the surface static?

Tags: opengl

```
#include<gl/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>

GLfloat vertices[][3]={
{0.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,0.4,0.0},{0.4,0.4,0.0},{0.4,0.0,0.0} };

GLfloat color[2][3]={ {1.0,0.0,0.0},{0.0,1.0,0.0}};

void board()
{
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex3f(-0.8,-0.8,0.0);
        glVertex3f(-0.8,0.80,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.80,0.80,0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.8,-0.80,0.0);
    glEnd();
}

void cube() 
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[3]);
    glEnd();    
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
    glViewport(0,0,600,600);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    cube();
    board();

    glFlush();
}

void mykey(int key,int x,int y)
{
    switch(key){
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  glTranslatef(-0.4,0.0,0.0); break;        
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: glTranslatef(0.4,0.0,0.0);  break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP:    glTranslatef(0.0,0.4,0.0);  break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  glTranslatef(0.0,-0.3,0.0); break;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}


void myinit()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,200,0,400,-1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
    glutCreateWindow("hello");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutSpecialFunc(mykey);
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene renderer. You want to change something? Then you have to redraw the whole thing.